# What's the meaning of "what gets put where"?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I came across the following sentence:

> **What gets put where** determines the particular type of the architecture.

What's the meaning of the phrase in bold?

Comment: It's a short way of saying "what things are chosen, and where those chosen things are placed".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a special form of question that combines two or more questions about the same thing.

1. *What stuff has to get put away?*
2. *Where does it all go?*

are both reasonable questions to ask in context, and they can be asked in sequence, as here.

But they can be asked simultaneously by using both question words *what* and *where*.

Question formation can only leave one question word at the beginning, and since
*What* represents the noun phrase that is the subject in both questions, it starts the question.
*Where* is an adverb and appears after the verb; it stays there, since *What* is already at the start.

That's all, really; just another way English has to combine clauses into shorter sentences.
There are lots more.

Answer (score 0):

"What gets put where" will mean: the location of 'what' is put 'where'. . .The vase (what) gets put down (where). 'Where' will 'what' go? It is 'what gets put where'.

Answer (score 0):

With a collection of items that need to be placed, for example, around a room or into a specific order, you would need to decide **what gets put where**. That is, which item will be placed in which place/position in the room/order.